# Extract ALL IP Addresses from a Microsoft Outlook Messsage using Macros

Tags: regex, excel, vba, outlook

I have been researching how to extract **all** IP addresses from an Outlook message and copy to an Excel spreadsheet.  I have a working example that works at extracting 1 IP address from the OL message to copies to Excel cells.  Current it copies 1 octet per cell but ideally I need the IP address in 1 cell.

Also I need the macro to check the full body of the message and extract ALL IP addresses.  There could be between 1 to 100 IP addresses in the message.

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis 10.1.1.10 aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum

This IP has been flagged 192.168.1.1
This IP has been flagged 192.168.1.2
This IP has been flagged 192.168.1.3
This IP has been flagged 192.168.1.4


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non 192.168.2.1 proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
```

**CODE**

```
Sub CopyToExcel(olItem As Outlook.MailItem)
 Dim xlApp As Object
 Dim xlWB As Object
 Dim xlSheet As Object
 Dim vText, vText2, vText3, vText4, vText5 As Variant
 Dim sText As String
 Dim rCount As Long
 Dim bXStarted As Boolean
 Dim enviro As String
 Dim strPath As String
 Dim Reg1 As Object
 Dim M1 As Object
 Dim M As Object

enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))
'the path of the workbook
 strPath = enviro & "\Documents\test.xlsx"
     On Error Resume Next
     Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
     If Err <> 0 Then
         Application.StatusBar = "Please wait while Excel source is opened ... "
         Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
         bXStarted = True
     End If
     On Error GoTo 0
     'Open the workbook to input the data
     Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath)
     Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1")

    'Find the next empty line of the worksheet
     rCount = xlSheet.Range("B" & xlSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     rCount = rCount + 1

     sText = olItem.Body

     Set Reg1 = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    ' \s* = invisible spaces
    ' \d* = match digits
    ' \w* = match alphanumeric

    With Reg1
         .Pattern = "((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))"

    End With
    If Reg1.Test(sText) Then

' each "(\w*)" and the "(\d)" are assigned a vText variable
        Set M1 = Reg1.Execute(sText)
        For Each M In M1
           vText = Trim(M.SubMatches(1))
           vText2 = Trim(M.SubMatches(2))
           vText3 = Trim(M.SubMatches(3))
           vText4 = Trim(M.SubMatches(4))
           ' vText5 = Trim(M.SubMatches(5))
        Next
    End If

  xlSheet.Range("B" & rCount) = vText
  xlSheet.Range("c" & rCount) = vText2
  xlSheet.Range("d" & rCount) = vText3
  xlSheet.Range("e" & rCount) = vText4
  xlSheet.Range("f" & rCount) = vText5

     xlWB.Close 1
     If bXStarted Then
         xlApp.Quit
     End If
     Set M = Nothing
     Set M1 = Nothing
     Set Reg1 = Nothing
     Set xlApp = Nothing
     Set xlWB = Nothing
     Set xlSheet = Nothing
 End Sub
```

Comment: The entire match (M) and also the first submatch group (submatches(0)) will contain the entire IP address.  Just put that into your cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern actually matches full IPv4 address, you may see it in this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zRZVKF/1). That means, you just need to grab the whole match, not the submatches.

Also, to get multiple occurrences (at regex101.com, see the `g` modifier), you need to set `Reg1.Global = True`.

So, use

```
With Reg1
    .Pattern = "((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))"
    .Global = True
End With
```

And then

```
For Each M In M1
    vText = Trim(M.Value)
Next
```

The rest of the code is not  hard to adjust.